# POV-Ray alternative

Tags: data-visualization, 3d

What the question says. I've looked around but I haven't found any alternatives to POV-Ray.
To clarify, I don't want just a renderer. It's important to be able to create a scene from text only. I don't create houses and furnitures. I work with mostly geometric shapes. Every alternative I've seen being suggested are basically whole engines (for Blender or otherwise) that use GUI.

The reason I want an alternative to POV-Ray is the speed and the community. POV-Ray is amazing but it can be slow on rendering multiple objects and I get the feeling that a lot of people are abandoning it, leaving few places where you can ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow in our makerspace is a big fan of POV-Ray and brought it up during one meeting where the discussion was focused on [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/). OpenSCAD is a text based 3D modeling program with capabilities in two dimensions, although limited. The 3D aspect is pretty comprehensive, supporting loops, conditionals, arrays, and many things that are beyond my pay grade, figuratively speaking.

OpenSCAD also supports animation of the viewing camera, not so much of the model movement. The following image is courtesy of the OpenSCAD home page.

OpenSCAD is supported on Windows, Mac and Linux.

[image: openscad screen shot]